# Conditional statement in GridView to show or hide HyperlinkField data

Tags: c#, gridview, data-binding

My code:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField Text="Static<br />Map" HeaderText=""               
           DataNavigateUrlFields="PWSNO,TAG_NO"                 
           Visible = '<%# Eval("Status").ToString() == "Inactive" ? false : true %>'                
            DataNavigateUrlFormatString="index.aspx?No={0}&tag={1}" 
            ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" Target="_blank" />
```

What I'm trying to do is if "Status" property returns value of "Inactive" I don't want a link in that column to be created.

But with my existing code I'm getting an error stating

> Error Databinding expressions are only supported on objects that have a DataBinding event. System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLinkField does not have a DataBinding event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `TemplateField` which has a DataBinding event.

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="">
    <asp:Hyperlink Text="Static<br />Map" Target="_blank"
     Visible = '<%# Eval("Status").ToString() == "Inactive" ? false : true %>'></asp:Hyperlink>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

You'll have to manually set the `NavigateUrl`.